# How to build a single BOM from a multimodule Maven project

Tags: maven

I would like to create a single BOM file for one of my team's projects. A Web search led me to [bom-builder-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jboss/bom-builder-maven-plugin).

It looked promising and it works very well for one-module projects, but unfortunately, it creates a BOM file per Maven module, effectively yielding 51 bom-pom.xml files for  that 50-module project.

I am looking for a more unified way of building that master BOM I'm aiming for, instead of having to manually copy the `dependencyManagement` sections of the 200+ such BOM files that would be created across our portfolio, with the risk of duplicate entries that I'd be running.

Ideally, I am looking for a plugin to which I could give a reference to an existing BOM and which would then add to it, or a plugin that can generate from scratch a single BOM for a multimodule project.

Comment: Why don't you have the `dependencyManagement` section in the parent of your multi module project (instead of inside the different modules)?

Comment: Good question! Because this is a legacy project; many non-sensible things have been done in it by non-knowledgeable people. Bad practices are all over the place, which is exactly what I'm trying to clean up.